# Use a function over multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, function, loops, text

I need to apply a wordcounter function to multiple columns with text. I need it to look like this:

[image]

The code I wrote is

```
written = data.loc[:, 'text1':'text3']
written = written.fillna('none')

def wordcounter (text):
    count = text.str.split().str.len()
    return count

for col in written.columns:
    written[col + '_ct'] = written.apply(wordcounter, axis=1, args=(col,))
```

But I get the error is TypeError: wordcounter() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Does anyone know what I should do? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can re-work the apply function to work with the column not as an argument but as a dataframe filter:

```
import pandas as pd


def wordcounter(text):
    return len(text.split())


data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
    {
        'text1': ['test words', 'more words'],
        'text2': ['words words', 'word'],
        'text3': ['words', 'word word'],
    }
)

written = data.loc[:, 'text1':'text3']
written = written.fillna('none')

for col in written.columns:
    written[col + '_ct'] = written[col].apply(wordcounter)

print(written)
```

Output

```
        text1        text2      text3  text1_ct  text2_ct  text3_ct
0  test words  words words      words         2         2         1        
1  more words         word  word word         2         1         2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `apply` your function column-wise instead of row-wise, since `.str.split().str.len()` are already "vectorized" operations.

Then you can combine the dataframes (your original `text` as well as the `counts` together into a final dataframe with all of the information.

```
def word_counter(series):
    return series.str.split().str.len()

counts_df = (df.apply(word_counter)   # apply our function column-wise 
               .add_suffix("_count")) # add a suffix of "_count" to the column names

final_df = df.join(counts_df)         # combine the original dataframe with the counts

print(final_df)
        text1        text2      text3  text1_count  text2_count  text3_count
0  test words  words words      words            2            2            1
1  more words         word  word word            2            1            2
```